# matrix kronecker product in series

Tags: matlab, matrix, series

everyone i want to make this matrix

```
C=[1 0] 
A=[1 2;1 2] 
B=[1 3;1 3]
```

into larger matrix like this

```
F = [ CB,        0,   0,   0,...
      CAB,      CB,   0,   0... 
      CA^2B,   CAB,  CB,   0,... 
      CA^3B, CA^2B,  CB,   0 ]
```

until sum of `A` is `A^n`

The problem why I can solve it because matrix `B` consist of 2 row and 2 col.
I try to use this function but just can if `B` consist of 2 row and 1 col.

```
    for i=1:n  
      for j=1:n
         S(i,j)=C*(A^(i-1)/A^(j-1))*B 
      end 
   end  
   S1=tril(S)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cells, and use recursion to reduce the number of multiplications performed

```
[S{ 1:(n+1), 1:(n+1) }] = deal(zeros( 1, 2 )); % pre-allocate
S{1,1} = C; % we'll take care of B later - don't worry.  
for k=1:n
    S{k+1,1} = S{k,1} * A; % assignment to cell content
    S(k+1,2:(k+1)) = S(k,1:k); % cell assignment - notice the regular parenthesis
end
S = cellfun( @(x) x*B, S, 'UniformOutput', false ); % now multiply by B
S = cell2mat( S );
```